# Raspberry Pi What can I do with it?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have read about the Raspberry Pi(https://superuser.com/tags/raspberry-pi/info and http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) and I was wondering a few things about it. I have read somethings you can do with it but I have no idea how I would be able to make it work like that.

- Can you exactly tell me what you can do with it and if it's easy to
  make it work like that?
- As an unexperienced person with these kind of things and hardware basically, should I buy it? (considering the answers to question 1 are usefull for me)
- If I would buy it, what should I buy with it?

The last 2 questions aren't really questions for this site, but I thought I could add it to this question as well.

**EDIT**:

Considering I'm getting downvotes for asking opinions as well, I would just be glad if the first question could be answered.

Comment: You have already read some uses for it so I won't repeat that list.  Sounds like the Raspberry PI isn't something you should purchase if you cannot even determine the reason you want it.  Superuser isn't a discussion forum, we cannot tell you, if you should buy it or not.

Comment: I've never used one, but simply reading the wiki tells me that it's a lightweight, cheap computer. So it can do anything that a lightweight, cheap computer can do with the peripherals that it has? If you don't even know the reason why you want one, I wouldn't buy it, and I certainly wouldn't ask in a place that is not here for opinion discussions.

Comment: @Ramhound Read the last sentence. The first question is just:"What are ALL the uses of it?"

Comment: @Moses Ok i thought it could do some different stuff with it as well.

Comment: @loko Asking what are all the uses of it is like asking "what can I use bricks to build?" Anything you want, the list is infinite! Based on that I'm inclined to flag this as "too broad."

Comment: @Moses "If you dont even know the reason why you want one, I wouldn't buy it" That's why I wanted to know the uses -.-

Comment: @James Thanks well I just got annoying pages with no usefull information. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @loko - If you are not willing to research what uses would interest you then I am not going to spend the time to list what likely are about a hundred different uses.  Several are on the Raspberry Pi website itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is a low cost computer, you do whatever you want with it that you
   could with a low cost computer.
2. If you need a new low cost computer, then buy it.
3. Just as if you bought a new motherboard, you will likely need to [a case for it](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/cases) too.